# Random encoding from a php array string not showing in html

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array where some strings show on my html and some don't, and upon dumping the array it seems to have to do with some random encoding. WHen I dump the array I get:

```
13 => {#903 ▼
    +"phrase": b"""Test String Number One"
}
16 => {#906 ▼

+"phrase": "Test String Number Two"
}
```

In my html, the Test String Number Two shows up but not Number One which has `b"""` before the string

This is in laravel using

```
@foreach($strings as $string)
    {{$string->phrase}}
@endforeach
```

How can I strip any of these unknown characters in order to show the phrase?

Comment: I had a similar problem once, and I solved using [utf8_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php). Check if it solves your problem too... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that string is a Binary String, you need to [unpack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) the data.

Regards.

Comment: I tried ```dd(unpack("c2chars/nint", $string))``` but it came back null